# List all SQL records occurring within x hours of another set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nested-sets, self-join

Am I even close on this?
I'm trying to list all the records that contain "Ape"... as well as all the
records that occur x days BEFORE any "Ape" record(s).
I guess I need a self-join table?

```
-- Doesn't work:
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  FROM TestTable As tblA                      WHERE tblA.MyPet='Ape'
UNION
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  FROM TestTable AS tblA, TestTable AS tblB   WHERE tblA.MyPet='Ape' AND tblA.MyDate>tblB.MyDate-0.5 AND tblA.MyDate<tblB.MyDate
ORDER BY tblA.MyDate ASC

-- Doesn't work:
SELECT * FROM TestTable As tblA     INNER JOIN TestTable As tblB ON tblA.MyPet =         'Ape'     AND tblA.MyDate>tblB.MyDate-1  AND tblA.MyKey>tblB.MyKey

-- Doesn't work:
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE MyDate IN (SELECT MyDate-1 FROM TestTable WHERE MyPet='Ape')

-- Doesn't work
SELECT id, uid, date FROM orders current
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT * from orders future 
   WHERE future.date < DateAdd(DAYS, 1, current.date)
   AND future.date > getdate()
   AND future.uid = current.uid
)

-- Doesn't work
SELECT * FROM TestTable AS tblA
WHERE EXISTS
( 
   SELECT * FROM TestTable AS tblB
   WHERE tblB < DateAdd(DAYS, 1, tblA.MyDate)
   AND tblB.MYDate > GetDate()
   AND tblA.MyKey = tblB.MyKey
)
```

=========================== Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable   
(
MyKey       Int             IDENTITY(1,1)   PRIMARY KEY,     

MyDate      DateTime        NOT NULL    DEFAULT GetDate(),
MyPet       VarChar(22)     NOT NULL    DEFAULT ''
)

INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 06:12:10', 'Cat'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 10:11:10', 'Dog'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 14:13:10', 'Fish'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 16:14:10', 'Duck'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 17:15:10', 'Bird'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('01-Dec-2012 20:16:10', 'Kitten')
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('02-Dec-2012 01:17:10', 'Dog'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('02-Dec-2012 12:19:10', 'Fish'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('02-Dec-2012 13:20:10', 'Duck'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('02-Dec-2012 14:21:10', 'Bird'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('02-Dec-2012 16:18:10', 'Cat'   )     -- These are within 1 day before any "Ape" record

INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 05:26:10', 'Dog'   )     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 11:22:10', 'Kitten')     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 12:23:10', 'Duck'  )     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 13:24:10', 'Bird'  )     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 14:25:10', 'Ape'   )     -- An "Ape" record
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('03-Dec-2012 16:27:10', 'Cat'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('04-Dec-2012 01:32:10', 'Dog'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('04-Dec-2012 04:28:10', 'Fish'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('04-Dec-2012 07:30:10', 'Bird'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('04-Dec-2012 10:31:10', 'Kitten')
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('04-Dec-2012 16:29:10', 'Duck'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('05-Dec-2012 11:35:10', 'Kitten')
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('05-Dec-2012 12:36:10', 'Duck'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('05-Dec-2012 13:33:10', 'Duck'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('05-Dec-2012 13:37:10', 'Bird'  )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('05-Dec-2012 14:34:10', 'Dog'   )
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('06-Dec-2012 04:41:10', 'Fish'  )     -- These are within 1 day before any "Ape" record
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('06-Dec-2012 05:39:10', 'Dog'   )     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('06-Dec-2012 14:38:10', 'Kitten')     --
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('06-Dec-2012 16:40:10', 'Ape'   )     -- An "Ape" record
INSERT INTO TestTable(MyDate, MyPet)   VALUES('06-Dec-2012 16:42:10', 'Duck'  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tblA.*
FROM TestTable AS tblA
    INNER JOIN TestTable AS tblB
        ON (tblA.MyDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, tblB.MyDate)) AND (tblA.MyDate <= tblB.Mydate) AND (tblB.MyPet = 'Ape');
```

Here's the working [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c91a0/4/0).

**UPDATE**

Added `DISTINCT` per Gordon's comment below.

Comment: . . I upvoted this, but to be accurate, it should be `select distinct tblA.*`, because you are going to get duplicates when more than one record matches.  You don't need an `outer join` (which you don't have) because the original record will always match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll update the answer with `DISTINCT`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the formulation you are looking for is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable tblA
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM TestTable tblB
              WHERE tblB.mydate between tblA.MyDate - X and tblA.MyDate and
                    tblB.MyPet = 'Ape'
             )
```

Two notes.  First, this uses the syntax "date - x" which works when date is a `datetime` but not a `date`.  It is equivalent to `dateadd(day, -x, tbla.MyDate)`.

Second, this will return all records with 'Ape' because `between` handles equality.

Jesse's query does essentially the same thing using an outer join and distinct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Process: write each half of the query separately and test to see that it works. Then put them together with a UNION.
2. If you are dropping duplicates, use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: I have no idea how to "write both halves". ("Then just join them with UNION" is the easy part.)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7594c/3)

**Query 1**:

```
-- Doesn't work:
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  
FROM TestTable As tblA
WHERE tblA.MyPet='Ape'
UNION all
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  
FROM TestTable AS tblA
WHERE dateadd(day, 1, tblA.MyDate) < (select min(MyDate) from TestTable where MyPet = 'Ape')
ORDER BY tblA.MyDate ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7594c/3/0)**:

```
|                          MYDATE |  MYPET |
--------------------------------------------
| December, 01 2012 06:12:10+0000 |    Cat |
| December, 01 2012 10:11:10+0000 |    Dog |
| December, 01 2012 14:13:10+0000 |   Fish |
| December, 01 2012 16:14:10+0000 |   Duck |
| December, 01 2012 17:15:10+0000 |   Bird |
| December, 01 2012 20:16:10+0000 | Kitten |
| December, 02 2012 01:17:10+0000 |    Dog |
| December, 02 2012 12:19:10+0000 |   Fish |
| December, 02 2012 13:20:10+0000 |   Duck |
| December, 02 2012 14:21:10+0000 |   Bird |
| December, 03 2012 14:25:10+0000 |    Ape |
| December, 06 2012 16:40:10+0000 |    Ape |
```

**EDIT**

if you need records occured **during** x days before first Ape record
then query should be (in example x = 1)

```
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  
FROM TestTable As tblA
WHERE tblA.MyPet='Ape'
UNION
SELECT tblA.MyDate, tblA.MyPet  
FROM TestTable AS tblA
WHERE (select min(MyDate) from TestTable where MyPet = 'Ape') between tblA.MyDate and dateadd(day, 1, tblA.MyDate)
ORDER BY tblA.MyDate ASC
```

Comment: That code+results is listing records farther back than... 1 day before any "ape" records.  (I see Dec 3rd APEs... then Dec 1st records.)